# how to reset max height of element on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to reset the max height of a `<p class="product_description">` in a set of responsive bootstrap columns.  However, this code only seems to work on initial document load and not the resize event.  What am I missing?

```
function DoEqualSizer(myclass) {
    var heights = $(myclass).map(function() {
        $(this).height('auto');
        return $(this).height();
    }).get(),
    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
    $(myclass).height(maxHeight);
};

function EqualSizer(myclass) {
    $(document).ready(DoEqualSizer(myclass));
    window.addEventListener('resize', DoEqualSizer(myclass));
};

EqualSizer('.product_description');
```

Comment: did you put your code in $(document).ready(function(){//all JS code here});

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify it as:

```
function EqualSizer(myclass) {
    $(document).ready(DoEqualSizer(myclass));
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() { DoEqualSizer(myclass); });
};
```